# Android app keeps crashing..why?

Tags: android

I have built an android app, but it does not seem stable. It is a large app with various Async tasks and takes photos, encrypts, decrypts files, prints to a Bluetooth printer.

However, it sometimes randomly crashes. What is the best way to find out the issue and am i not doing something right? If i run it in debug it works fine, it only crashs now and then.

Sometimes i restart the galaxy tablet it is on and it works fine for a while again. Am i not closing something correctly? whats the best way to test and find out the issue?

Should i have these many threads running?

[image]

```
     11-10 16:20:30.495: ERROR/StorageNotification(2489): onStorageStateChanged :: Media { /mnt/sdcard } state changed from { unmounted } -> { checking }
11-10 16:20:30.773: ERROR/WifiHW(2489): wifi_connect_to_supplicant:IFACE_DIR(/data/misc/wifi), iface(eth0), ifname(/data/misc/wifi/eth0)
11-10 16:20:30.773: ERROR/WifiHW(2489): wifi_connect_to_supplicant: ifname(/data/misc/wifi/eth0)
11-10 16:20:31.097: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(2489): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
11-10 16:20:31.694: ERROR/DftBootBroadcastReceiver(2715): SHOULD_SHUT_DOWN_F set complete
11-10 16:20:31.694: ERROR/DftBootBroadcastReceiver(2715): wrong Action : android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
11-10 16:20:31.874: ERROR/Setting(2590): Intent Action android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
11-10 16:20:31.976: ERROR/STKReceiver(2579): onReceive android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
11-10 16:20:32.593: ERROR/CscParser(2579): fileName + /system/csc/customer.xml
11-10 16:20:32.694: ERROR/CscReceiver(2579): onReceive android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
11-10 16:20:32.702: ERROR/CscParser(2579): fileName + /system/SW_Configuration.xml
11-10 16:20:32.718: ERROR/CscReceiver(2579): PATH_CSCNAME =CustomerDataSet.CSCName
11-10 16:20:32.737: ERROR/CscReceiver(2579): check_3
11-10 16:20:32.765: ERROR/CscUpdateService(2579): onStart
11-10 16:20:36.444: ERROR/NetworkStateTracker(2489): net.tcp.buffersize.hsdpa not found in system properties. Using defaults
11-10 16:20:36.530: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(2489): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
11-10 16:20:36.929: ERROR/MTP-LAUNCHER(2585): Action : file:///system/media
11-10 16:20:37.761: ERROR/StorageNotification(2489): onStorageStateChanged :: Media { /mnt/sdcard } state changed from { checking } -> { mounted }
11-10 16:20:37.773: ERROR/StorageNotification(2489): onStorageStateChanged :: Media { /mnt/sdcard/external_sd } state changed from { unmounted } -> { checking }
11-10 16:20:38.530: ERROR/SMSDispatcher(2579): intent.getAction() : android.provider.Telephony.GET_SMSC
11-10 16:20:39.687: ERROR/Setting(2590): Intent Action android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED
11-10 16:20:39.687: ERROR/Setting(2590): media scanner start is first time. 
11-10 16:20:39.690: ERROR/Setting(2590): Battery charging. plugType = 0
11-10 16:20:39.690: ERROR/Setting(2590): AC charge
11-10 16:20:40.433: ERROR/FastDormancy(2579):  before ======= ENTER DORMANCY =======
11-10 16:20:40.753: ERROR/FastDormancy(2579): [FD] Before mDormFlag: false in getCapaDormancy()
11-10 16:20:40.753: ERROR/FastDormancy(2579): [FD] After mDormFlag: false in getCapaDormancy()
11-10 16:20:41.565: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED
11-10 16:20:41.577: ERROR/(2991): In JNI_OnLoad
11-10 16:20:41.577: ERROR/(2991): initClassHelper: clearing local reference3
11-10 16:20:41.577: ERROR/(2991): initClassHelper: clearing local reference obj
11-10 16:20:41.577: ERROR/(2991): In register_android_MTP_StackInterface
11-10 16:20:41.640: ERROR/MTPRX(2991): Battery charging. plugType = 0
11-10 16:20:41.640: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): Not of USB charging. Dont lauch MTP APP
11-10 16:20:41.659: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
11-10 16:20:41.714: ERROR/BootReceiver(2985): registerContentObserver
11-10 16:20:41.741: ERROR/RequestQueueHelper(2964): [Thread-10/10] Next pending job not found!!
11-10 16:20:42.060: ERROR/StorageNotification(2489): onStorageStateChanged :: Media { /mnt/sdcard/external_sd } state changed from { checking } -> { mounted }
11-10 16:20:42.077: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
11-10 16:20:42.089: ERROR/BootReceiver(2985): registerContentObserver
11-10 16:20:42.093: ERROR/MediaScannerReceiver(2581): skip scan[/mnt/sdcard/external_sd] because InternalSD is now scanning
11-10 16:20:45.077: ERROR/libnetutils(2489): dhcp start cmd 11 : [dhcpcd:-ABK] 
11-10 16:20:45.855: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(2489): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
11-10 16:20:45.898: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(2489): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
11-10 16:20:45.960: ERROR/InstalledAppDetails(2590): setPackageList() configFilename:/system/etc/uninstall_lock_packages.txt
11-10 16:20:45.972: ERROR/InstalledAppDetails(2590): Application package name = com.android.qservices
11-10 16:20:45.972: ERROR/InstalledAppDetails(2590): Packages = com.gameloft.android.GAND.GloftNOHP
11-10 16:20:46.792: ERROR/CscReceiver(2579): onReceive android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
11-10 16:20:46.847: ERROR/MTP-LAUNCHER(2585): Action : file:///system/media
11-10 16:20:46.964: ERROR/CscReceiver(2579): check_9
11-10 16:20:47.132: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
11-10 16:20:47.175: ERROR/MTP-LAUNCHER(2585): Action : file:///mnt/sdcard
11-10 16:20:47.226: ERROR/BootReceiver(2985): Ignore first ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
11-10 16:20:47.304: ERROR/Setting(2590): Intent Action android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED
11-10 16:20:47.304: ERROR/Setting(2590): media scanner start is not the first time. So return = 
11-10 16:20:47.331: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED
11-10 16:20:47.413: ERROR/MTPRX(2991): Battery charging. plugType = 0
11-10 16:20:47.413: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): Not of USB charging. Dont lauch MTP APP
11-10 16:20:47.612: ERROR/MediaScanner(2581): Be careful if the code ends up here!!!  mDbEntryToDelete : 1
11-10 16:20:47.792: ERROR/RequestQueueHelper(2964): [OPSWorkerThread-1320942041797/14] Next pending job not found!!
11-10 16:20:48.940: ERROR/Database(2627): Error inserting package=com.android.mms class=com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList badgecount=0
11-10 16:20:48.940: ERROR/Database(2627): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

11-10 17:18:43.549: ERROR/WifiService(2489): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
11-10 17:23:39.526: ERROR/WifiService(2489): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
11-10 17:23:39.526: ERROR/WifiService(2489): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
11-10 18:05:52.553: ERROR/WifiService(2489): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
11-10 18:05:52.553: ERROR/WifiService(2489): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
11-10 21:05:52.549: ERROR/WifiService(2489): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
11-10 21:05:52.549: ERROR/WifiService(2489): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
11-10 23:18:45.549: ERROR/WifiService(2489): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
11-10 23:18:45.549: ERROR/WifiService(2489): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
11-11 05:05:55.561: ERROR/WifiService(2489): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
11-11 05:05:55.561: ERROR/WifiService(2489): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
11-11 09:20:14.510: ERROR/ShutdownThread(2489): IsShutDownStarted()
11-11 09:20:14.510: ERROR/WindowManager(2489): isWakeKey=true isKeyDown=true isMusicActive=false
11-11 09:20:14.510: ERROR/WindowManager(2489): onWakeKeyWhenKeyguardShowingTq=true
11-11 09:20:14.510: ERROR/WindowManager(2489): if isWakeKey && isKeyDown
11-11 09:20:14.522: ERROR/SensorManager(2489): registerListener 4:P1 LightSensor delay:240
11-11 09:20:14.522: ERROR/SensorManager(2489): =======>>>Sensor Thread RUNNING <<<========
11-11 09:20:14.846: ERROR/ShutdownThread(2489): IsShutDownStarted()
11-11 09:20:14.866: ERROR/ShutdownThread(2489): IsShutDownStarted()
11-11 09:20:14.869: ERROR/SensorManager(2489): registerListener 1:BMA150 delay:60
11-11 09:20:14.916: ERROR/ShutdownThread(2489): IsShutDownStarted()
11-11 09:20:14.971: ERROR/SensorManager(2489): unregisterListener: com.android.server.PowerManagerService$12@47f4b578
11-11 09:20:14.998: ERROR/SensorManager(2489): unregisterListener: android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@48197c88
11-11 09:20:15.116: ERROR/FastDormancy(2579): [SCREEN_ON] New FD Time: 5000
11-11 09:20:15.147: ERROR/WifiService(2489): =========shouldWifiStayAwake: wifiSleepPolicy 2
11-11 09:20:15.159: ERROR/FastDormancy(2579): [SCREEN_OFF] New FD Time: 5000
11-11 09:20:15.843: ERROR/ShutdownThread(2489): IsShutDownStarted()
11-11 09:20:15.846: ERROR/WindowManager(2489): isWakeKey=true isKeyDown=true isMusicActive=false
11-11 09:20:15.846: ERROR/WindowManager(2489): onWakeKeyWhenKeyguardShowingTq=true
11-11 09:20:15.846: ERROR/WindowManager(2489): if isWakeKey && isKeyDown
11-11 09:57:51.600: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED
11-11 09:57:52.784: ERROR/StorageNotification(2489): onStorageStateChanged :: Media { /mnt/sdcard } state changed from { mounted } -> { unmounted }
11-11 09:57:52.815: ERROR/MediaProvider(2581): mUnmountReceiver - Intent.getAction : android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED, path[/mnt/sdcard]
11-11 09:57:52.842: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED
11-11 09:57:52.873: ERROR/StorageNotification(2489): onStorageStateChanged :: Media { /mnt/sdcard } state changed from { unmounted } -> { shared }
11-11 09:59:03.530: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED
11-11 09:59:03.600: ERROR/MediaProvider(2581): mUnmountReceiver - Intent.getAction : android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED, path[/mnt/sdcard]
11-11 09:59:03.639: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED
11-11 09:59:03.651: ERROR/StorageNotification(2489): onStorageStateChanged :: Media { /mnt/sdcard } state changed from { shared } -> { unmounted }
11-11 09:59:03.995: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED
11-11 09:59:04.620: ERROR/MediaProvider(2581): mUnmountReceiver - Intent.getAction : android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED, path[/mnt/sdcard/external_sd]
11-11 09:59:04.635: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
11-11 09:59:04.670: ERROR/BootReceiver(3325): registerContentObserver
11-11 09:59:05.151: ERROR/HJ(2581): ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED. shutDown : false, ums : false, mSdSerial : null
11-11 09:59:05.182: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED
11-11 09:59:05.205: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
11-11 09:59:05.213: ERROR/BootReceiver(3325): registerContentObserver
11-11 09:59:05.276: ERROR/MediaScannerReceiver(2581): skip scan[/mnt/sdcard/external_sd] because InternalSD is now scanning
11-11 09:59:05.299: ERROR/MTP-LAUNCHER(2585): Action : file:///mnt/sdcard
11-11 09:59:05.299: ERROR/Setting(2590): Intent Action android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED
11-11 09:59:05.299: ERROR/Setting(2590): media scanner start is not the first time. So return = 
11-11 09:59:05.307: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED
11-11 09:59:05.334: ERROR/MTPRX(2991): Battery charging. plugType = 0
11-11 09:59:05.334: ERROR/MTPRx(2991): Not of USB charging. Dont lauch MTP APP
11-11 09:59:05.709: ERROR/StorageNotification(2489): onStorageStateChanged :: Media { /mnt/sdcard } state changed from { unmounted } -> { checking }
11-11 09:59:05.734: ERROR/StorageNotification(2489): onStorageStateChanged :: Media { /mnt/sdcard } state changed from { checking } -> { mounted }
11-11 09:59:05.741: ERROR/StorageNotification(2489): onStorageStateChanged :: Media { /mnt/sdcard/external_sd } state changed from { shared } -> { unmounted }android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1919)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:883)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:960)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:953)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:600)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at com.android.qservices.AdminActivity.inputStreamToString(AdminActivity.java:462)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at com.android.qservices.AdminActivity$CreateTablesTask.doInBackground(AdminActivity.java:268)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at com.android.qservices.AdminActivity$CreateTablesTask.doInBackground(AdminActivity.java:1)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
11-11 10:06:05.870: ERROR/Database(3497):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.android.qservices/databases/q.db' 
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1919)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:883)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:960)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:953)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:600)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at com.android.qservices.IncidentIdService$UploadFilesTask.doInBackground(IncidentIdService.java:83)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
11-11 10:06:05.916: ERROR/Database(3497):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
11-11 10:06:06.276: ERROR/Camera(3553): onDestroy() exit
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.android.qservices/databases/q.db' 
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1919)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:883)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:960)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:953)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:600)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at com.android.qservices.IncidentPhotoActivity.getIncidentPicId(IncidentPhotoActivity.java:59)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at com.android.qservices.IncidentPhotoActivity.initAvatar(IncidentPhotoActivity.java:80)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at com.android.qservices.IncidentPhotoActivity.onCreate(IncidentPhotoActivity.java:54)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
11-11 10:06:31.991: ERROR/Database(3497):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 10:06:36.995: ERROR/CachedBluetoothDeviceManager(2590): Got bonding state changed for 00:22:58:0B:BE:BE, but we have no record of that device.
11-11 10:06:37.233: ERROR/InputMethodService(2574): Keyboard State : 0
11-11 10:06:52.514: ERROR/DBUS-HCI(2819): ...get_auth_requirements unimplemented
11-11 10:06:52.526: ERROR/ADAPTER(2819): Unable to add connection 257
11-11 10:07:25.729: ERROR/InputMethodService(2574): Keyboard State : 0
11-11 10:07:28.463: ERROR/InputMethodService(2574): Keyboard State : 0
11-11 10:07:28.467: ERROR/InputMethodService(2574): Keyboard State : 0
11-11 10:07:30.803: ERROR/InputMethodService(2574): Keyboard State : 0
11-11 10:07:42.561: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:07:42.623: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:07:42.741: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:07:42.834: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:07:47.038: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:07:47.788: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:07:49.565: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:07:49.584: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:07:49.616: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:07:49.623: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:07:50.010: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:07:50.073: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3497): error: /mnt/sdcard/external_sd/QBics/SendQ/1_855_J7_Incidents.txt (No such file or directory)
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3497): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/external_sd/QBics/SendQ/1_855_J7_Incidents.txt (No such file or directory)
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3497):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3497):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3497):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:82)
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3497):     at com.android.qservices.UploadService$UploadFilesTask.doInBackground(UploadService.java:204)
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3497):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3497):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3497):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3497):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3497):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/MediaPlayer(3497):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
11-11 10:07:50.123: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:07:50.147: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:07:50.166: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:07:50.717: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:07:50.721: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:07:50.803: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:07:50.807: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:09:07.788: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:09:07.811: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:09:07.851: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:09:07.854: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:09:11.506: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:09:11.538: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:09:11.600: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:09:11.608: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:09:12.123: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:09:12.143: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:09:12.213: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:09:12.217: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:09:12.831: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:09:12.842: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:09:12.916: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:09:12.920: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:09:13.549: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:09:13.553: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:09:13.635: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:09:13.635: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:11:16.373: ERROR/PowerManagerService(2489): CurLock p:3 mPS:1
11-11 10:11:25.385: ERROR/InputMethodService(2574): Keyboard State : 0
11-11 10:11:29.823: ERROR/InputMethodService(2574): Keyboard State : 0
11-11 10:11:29.827: ERROR/InputMethodService(2574): Keyboard State : 0
11-11 10:11:30.014: ERROR/InputMethodService(2574): Keyboard State : 0
11-11 10:11:32.104: ERROR/InputMethodService(2574): Keyboard State : 0
11-11 10:12:19.858: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:12:19.862: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:12:19.918: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:12:19.944: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:12:20.526: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:12:20.530: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:12:20.605: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:12:20.616: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:12:21.233: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:12:21.245: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:12:21.331: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:12:21.331: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:12:22.053: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:12:22.053: ERROR/fileupload(3497): Start
11-11 10:12:22.131: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:12:22.139: ERROR/fileupload(3497): after writeByte
11-11 10:14:24.948: ERROR/PowerManagerService(2489): CurLock p:3 mPS:1
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions thrown?

Comment: Not when im debugging, it randomly crashes when it is installed independently on the tab, it just says "stopped unexpectedly. please try again "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 3:**
You also seem to get a `FileNotFoundException` on a text file (`/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/QBics/SendQ/1_855_J7_Incidents.txt`, I assume this is the CSV file you mention in your comments below). Is it guaranteed that a file is always present to parse?

**EDIT 2:**
I might have made a misleading point in my previous edit: According to some comments here below the internal memory in Android devices (in general?) suffer from roughly the same limitations as do the SD-cards as far as the write limit is concerned, hence, the "wear" caused by frequent writing shouldn't be a restrictive factor when choosing where to put the database (the internal memory will be just as much worn out as the SD-card would be).

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks for the log output.

I see a lot of exceptions in the logs which complain about databases not being closed properly and SD-card being unmounted or not available.

Does your application write to a database? Is that database stored on the SD-card? If yes, try to move the database to the internal storage instead.

It's usually not recommended to put databases on SD-cards while the SD-card isn't always accessible. The SD-card is also visible to all installed apps which raises questions regarding security. And from an even wider perspective; the SD-card has a limited lifespan as far as the number of writes that can be done to the card. That number is indeed huge, but nevertheless it's there...

**ORIGIN:**
I would connect the device to the development machine (through the USB cable) and issue an `adb logcat` in the Terminal directly after the app crashes. You will then get a log print which might show you information on what went wrong.

Comment: What is does is gets csv files from the sd card and then it creates tables on the internal memory from the column names in the csv

Comment: Maybe im not closing connections to the db, how do i do this? im using functions like the following... db.insert(DBAdapter.TableName, null, values);

Comment: String SQL = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"; 
        final Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL, null); 
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

Comment: @dbm The number of possible write ops on an SD card is of the same (limited) order as the number of writes to "internal" non-volatile memory; same technology in both.

Comment: @Beginner You can close a database connection with the `close()` method. I'm not sure if the method is called on the actual database object or the returned Cursor. You also use `startManagingCursor()` which should synchronize the lifespan of the Cursor with the lifespan of the parent Activity, but that doesn't necessarily open or close your database as well (it only manages the Cursor).

Comment: @HannoBinder Oh, I didn't know they were of the same kind. Sorry for the misleading information. I'll correct my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/). This will allow you to obtain a stacktrace whenever your app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are running the code in debug mode, you are running it for a very small time and that why it is not crashing then. I am getting a feeling that after sometime, due to more process or improper code for handling memory, the application is going out of memory.

Try debugging the app for a longer time and keep a watch at your logcat. Try to log the exceptions in custom log messages and create custom log entry in eclipse in logcat tab. This will give you logs related to you application in separate tab. Also, try to handle exception at all levels.

Without knowing exceptions, you won't be able to know the cause.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Ok i will give this a go, because i also think this is the case, thats why when i restart the tab it works fine for a while longer

Comment: I was wondering is there a way of maybe clearing the memory or something, so within the app you could click a button to do this?

Comment: Clearing a memory explicitly is not a good idea. The virtual machine is already designed in such a way that it tries to kill other unnecessary processes when your application demands more memory. The best way is to ensure in coding itself and use good coding practices to avoid unnecessary clot in memory...
Please see if there is a memory issue, or a thread race issue as said by @Hanno.
These are the two most striking conditions in your case.

Comment: And, by the way, "clearing" memory with some magic operation is simply *not* possible in the Java environment. Do whatever you want, but as long as an object is "live" it cannot and it will not be removed from memory. The only way to release memory is to clear *all* live references ("object variables") to an unneeded object, either explicitly like in *someObject = null;* or implicitly when a variable goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] with various Async tasks [...]
>   it only crashes now and then

and

> in debug it works fine

This certainly rings a (loud!) bell for me: Your problem may well be related to synchronization issues between concurrently running activities; keyword: [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing). This is one of the hardest problems to reproduce or debug.

So have a close look at the synchronization of your activities.

And one general note: Those "force close" errors are most often caused by an uncaught exception in an app, which will a) be reflected in the logcat and b) can easily be dealt with via proper exception handling.

Comment: Please see edit...Should i have all them running? How do i close them if not

Comment: I don't know how many async. tasks you *want* to be running. However, the *number* of tasks does *not* cause race conditions.